# htaccess RewriteRule 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, http-status-code-404

I want to change this url

```
http://localhost/RedHat/movbase-backbone/php/sql/movie.php
```

Into this

```
http://localhost/RedHat/movbase-backbone/movie
```

I tried creating a rule in my .htaccess file but whenever I go to /movie I get a 404 error.

Here is my rule

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^movie/?$ php/sql/movie.php [NC,L]
```

I have tried changing movie.php out with other files in order to see if they would work and I didn't get any problems.

Is there something wrong with my rule?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file located at `/RedHat/movbase-backbone/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /RedHat/movbase-backbone/
RewriteRule ^movie/?$ php/sql/movie.php [NC,L]
```

This assumes your document root is at `http://localhost/`.

Do you really want to allow both `movie` and `movie/`?

Comment: My .htaccess is located at /RedHat/movbase-backbone/.htaccess. I am using the url for a rest api so I would like to have movie and movie/ both work. Later I would like to have movie/:id, where :id is a movie id, but I can work through that later.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. When I try visiting either movie or movie/ I get a 404 error. The 404 error has a link that sends me to the folder containing my php file, so php/sql. Here is the error page I am getting [link](http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn165/Kcross911/Untitled_zpsla9xzsxy.png)

Comment: By itself the above should work. Do you have other directives in this .htaccess file? Do you have other .htaccess files in parent directories? Try changing the above `RewriteRule` into a temporary redirect (ie. include the `R` flag) - does it redirect?

Comment: The only other directive I have in the .htaccess file is one checking for 404 errors. I only have the one .htaccess file. When I do include the R flag the page does redirect and work properly.

Comment: If a _redirect_ (ie. with the `R` flag) works correctly and an _internal rewrite_ does not, it sounds as if your server-side code is perhaps dependent on the request URL?

Comment: Yes, I am having different functionality for my api based on the url. For example when  `php/sql/movie.php` is used all the movies are retrieved, but if `php/sql/movie.php/:id` is used only the movie with that `id` will be selected.

Comment: Well, obviously when you do an internal rewrite (ie. you have changed the URL) - as above - then the requested URL is now different, so you will have to change your API accordingly? The requested URL is now `movie`, not `php/sql/movie.php`. But also, you did not mention `/:id` in your question? This adds an additional complexity which is not currently handled by the code above.

Comment: I will take a look at my API to see if there are problems with it. I didn't mention the /:id because I was hoping to get the base get to work first and then branch out. Thank you for the help so far.